# Minimum elements of two arrays

Tags: php

guys!

Does the PHP have a ready-made function for finding the minimum elements from two different arrays?

For example:

```
$arr1 = [1,4,5,8];
$arr2 = [2,3,6,7];
$arr3 = [];
```

I have to compare `$arr1[0]` and `$arr2[0]`  and push minimum of them into `$arr3`

`$arr3` should contain `[1,3,5,7]`

Comment: There's no ready-made function for this that I know have. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're fine with two function, you can use:

```
$arr3 = array_map('min',$arr1,$arr2);
```